# Objective-C property assignment returns the assigned value?

Tags: objective-c, gcc, compiler-construction, objective-c-runtime

Say I have the following:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject { NSString* _foobar; }
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* foobar;
@end

@implementation MyClass
@dynamic foobar;
- (void) setFoobar:(NSString*)fbSet; { [_foobar release]; _foobar = [fbSet retain]; }
- (NSString*) foobar; { return _foobar; }
@end
```

Then:

```
MyClass* mcInst = [[[MyClass alloc] init] autorelease];
NSLog(@"I set 'foobar' to '%@'", (mcInst.foobar = @"BAZ!"));
```

Looking at the return value of `-[MyClass setFoobar:]`, one might assume here that this line would print `I set 'foobar' to ''`, because the assignment appears to return nothing.

However - thankfully - this assignment acts as expected, and the code prints `I set 'foobar' to 'BAZ!'`. Unfortunately, this feels like a contradiction, because the invoked setter's return value belies the fact that the assignment returns the value assigned to it. At first I figured that `mcInst.foobar = @"BAZ!";` is making two calls instead a block: first the setter and then the getter to gather the return value. However, instrumenting the setter and getter methods with `NSLog` calls proves this isn't the case.

Comment: I think rather than "Why does the NSLog work?", a better question (and I think the question you are asking) is "why does the setter return void, and not (in this case) NSString* ? I also had assumed that mcInst.foobar =  was just syntactic sugar for [mcInst setFoobar: ...] I guess not...

Comment: Yes, the question is why does the compiler throw an error when you use `NSLog(@"I set 'foobar' to '%@'", [mcInst setFoobar: @"BAZ!"]);` acknowledging that the method does not return anything, but allows you to do it the other way.

Comment: Brian: yes, that was in fact the question I was trying to ask, although my wording may have hidden that =)

Comment: Dimitris: your example is a perfect exposition of exactly what my question is about. If the property syntax really does simply compile down to a message send, and that message returns void, than why does it work at all?!

Comment: What I understand from this conversation is that the property syntax does *not* compile to `[mcInst setFoobar: @"BAZ!"]`. And I believe e.James' answer shows exactly what the compiler does. Thanks for a useful post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Quick Summary:**

The quick answer here is that there is no contradiction, because the result of the expression:

```
(mcInst.foobar = @"BAZ!")
```

is actually `@"BAZ!"`, and *not* `mcInst.foobar`.

More detail is available below, but it might help to consider the following modification to your `setFoobar` method:

```
- (void) setFoobar:(NSString*)fbSet
{
    [_foobar release];
    _foobar = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"HELLO_%@", fbSet] retain];
}
```

With this code in place, the value of the `foobar` property is modified while it is being set, *but your line of code will still display the value 'BAZ!'*.

**Details:**

As pointed out by [newacct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060236/objective-c-property-assignment-returns-the-assigned-value/2060352#2060352), your NSLog code works because you use the assignment operator (=), which has some very specific behaviour in the C language (which Objective-C is based upon)

In C, you can do the following:

```
x = y = z = 42;
```

and all of the variables, `x`, `y` and `z` will hold the value 42.

The compiler handles this behaviour by using a temporary variable(*). Essentially, what happens behind the scenes looks something like this:

```
tempVar = 42;
z = tempVar;
y = tempVar;
x = tempVar;
```

Along the same lines, you can do the following:

```
SomeFunction(x = 42);
```

this line of code will copy the value of 42 into x, and then call `SomeFunction` with an argument of 42. Behind the scenes, it looks like this:

```
tempVar = 42;
x = tempVar;
SomeFunction(tempVar);
```

Now, in Objective-C, your logging line is handled as follows:

```
tempVar = @"BAZ!";
[mcInst setFooBar:tempVar];
NSLog(@"I set 'foobar' to '%@'", tempVar);
```

(*) note that the usage of a "temporaray variable" I describe is meant to illustrate the concept, and may not actually reflect what any given compiler actually does under the hood. That sort of implementation detail is up to the programmers who write the compiler, and each one may do something different. The end result, however, is the same.

Comment: I understand the C behavior and how it is accomplished by the compiler. I suppose your point of the compiler using a temp variable makes sense, so thank you. However, the focus of my question was on the apparent contradiction between a method returning void (which is what the property syntax in Objective-C boils down to) and the assignment returning the assigned value.

Comment: Hmm. I think I may have buried the key concept underneath too much detail. If you take a look at the last code block in my answer, you can see why the use of a temporary variable makes the return value of the property accessor irrelevant. The property accessor is simply called as one of the steps in executing your `NSLog(...)` line, and it is the temporary variable which gets passed to `NSLog`.

Comment: I put the critical point at the top of my answer, and added another example which might help to illustrate. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to call a getter — it has the value being assigned right there on the same line. You can think of it as expanding to `[mcInst setFoobar:@"BAZ!"], @"BAZ!"`.

Answer (score 0):

in C, assignment is an expression, which evaluates to the assigned value

Comment: I understand, and even pointed that out. I'm looking for the details of Objective-C's implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the way the C assignment operator works. As described in the ANSI C standard:

"An assignment operator stores a value in the object designated by
the left operand.  An assignment expression has the value of the left
operand after the assignment..."

Your assignment expression is `mcInst.foobar = @"BAZ!"`. It seems to make sense to me that even though the assignment works by calling a method on mcInst the behaviour the same as with C. The value of the assignment expression is the left operand after the assignment (`@"BAZ!"`) so this value is passed to the NSLog function.

This is the same behaviour that allows you to write an initialiser in the style of `if (self = [super init])`.

P.S. It is a fair question to ask why would the compiler call the setter on the property when assigning the value to it and not call the getter when using the value of `mcInst.foobar` afterwards. I'd say that it's simply assumed the getter will return the same value that was just assigned to the property and therefore the getter is not called.