# Does "LValue" not mean what I think it means?

Tags: objective-c, setter, lvalue

In the following code:

```
_imageView.hasHorizontalScroller = YES;
_imageView.hasVerticalScroller = YES;
_imageView.autohidesScrollers = YES;

NSLog(@"scrollbar? H %p V %p hide %p", 
      &(_imageView.hasHorizontalScroller), 
      &(_imageView.hasVerticalScroller),
      &(_imageView.autohidesScrollers));
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Controller.m:143: error: lvalue required as unary '&' operand
Controller.m:144: error: lvalue required as unary '&' operand
Controller.m:145: error: lvalue required as unary '&' operand
```

Notice that I am USING those variables as lvalues directly before the & lines...

How can it complain that a value isn't an lvalue right after I assign to it with no error? does this have to do with the magical getters/setters that objective C creates?

I think I need to explain some context to explain WHY I'm trying to get  the address:

in my previous SO post, I showed the same code, printing %d and finding  that after the assignments, the properties were still 0 for some reason. So, I figured I'd try to get the addresses of the properties to see where they're being stored and maybe I can figure out why I'm not successfully assigning to them, and then this happened.

I think that as people have mentioned, yeah, it's probably that when I do the assigment obj-c is secretly replacing that with a call to the setter (and then some other magic because in another SO post, someone else mentioned that

```
BOOL b = [_imageView setHasVerticleScroller: YES]
```

fails, but

```
BOOL b = _imageView.hasVerticalScroller = YES;
```

works fine.

Comment: Just curious, but why do you want to print the memory address?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why the values are all 0 after the assignments, and hoped that knowing WHERE they were would help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_imageView.hasHorizontalScroller = YES;` - in this line you access property in imageView - so you do not actually access value, but call **setter** method:

```
[_imageView  setHasHorizontalScroller:YES]; // Equivalent of your code.
```

In second example you also access property, but this time getter method gets called and returns BOOL. So as mipadi points you do not need to use `&` in that NSLog statement. 

I'd suggest to read docs about [properties](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html) in obj-c.

**Edit:** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060236/objective-c-property-assignment-returns-the-assigned-value) you can find the discussion about why properties work in multiple assignment statements like you mentioned:

```
BOOL b = _imageView.hasVerticalScroller = YES;
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure, but I'm going to take a stab at the answer.

Those properties are all `BOOL` types, which is (I believe) an `unsigned char` in Objective-C. (Maybe an `int`, I can't remember, but it's something like that.) So you're trying to take the address of (`&`) those properties. But you're not actually accessing the ivars directly; properties go through a method call to get their values. So you're trying to get the address of the `BOOL` return value of a method, but since you're not actually assigning the value *to* anything, there is no address -- you just have the value.

You'd have the same problem if you did this:

```
static int returnOne(void)
{
    return 1;
}

// Later...

NSLog(@"returnOne is %p", &returnOne());    // Oops, the return value of returnOne has no address!
```

Your log call should look like this:

```
NSLog(@"scrollbar? H %d V %d hide %d", 
  _imageView.hasHorizontalScroller, 
  _imageView.hasVerticalScroller,
  _imageView.autohidesScrollers);
```

Comment: my log call isn't actually trying to show the VALUES. I want the locations, as a debugging step... I already know the values are all 0, and I'm trying to figure out why...

Comment: Right, but the point is, the values don't have an address -- they have no location -- since they're just being returned from a method call and aren't being assigned. Properties are actually *method calls* -- you're not accessing the variable itself.

Comment: Well, that raises the question of why chained assignments work... but that may be another special case...

Comment: You mean, something like `obj.property.anotherProperty = otherObj`? That is basically the same as `[[obj property] setAnotherProperty:otherObj]`; you're not taking the address of at any point, so there's no reason it shouldn't work.

Comment: No, I mean 
     BOOL b = _imageView.hasHorizontalScroller = YES;

DOES in fact work. however, since the setter returns void,
     b = [_imageView setHasHorizontalScroller: YES];

 does NOT work.

Comment: That's because `BOOL b = _imageView.hasHorizontalScroller = YES` is probably equivalent to something like `[_imageView hasHorizontalScroller:YES]; BOOL b = [_imageView horizontalScroller]`.

Comment: something like it, but not that exactly because the problem I'm ACTUALLY trying to solve is figure out why the horizontal scroller setter isn't working. After this statement, [_imageView hasHorizontalScroller] returns 0, which is my fundamental problem...

Comment: Well, again, you're taking the address of, which isn't valid. `_imageView.hasHorizontalScroller` is turned into `[_imageView hasHorizontalScroller]`, which returns a `BOOL`. Then you're basically doing `&[_imageView hasHorizontalScroller]`. *But* that method *does not* return the ivar itself, because a `BOOL` is *not* an object. So you're trying to get the *address of* a *return value*, but the *return value* does *not* have an address (since it's not an object and the return val is not a pointer).

Comment: Now I'm confused. ignoring the dots and the &s, [_imageView setHasHorizontalScroller: YES]; NSLog(@"horizontal %d", [_imageView hasHorizontalScroller]); prints out horizontal 0. My fundamental problem is that I'm trying to figure outwhy...